# magento observer duplicate price bug

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I'm trying to include a JavaScript countdown and price of product on the product page and also in the category page but I have the following bug: for RWD theme because of tier price, the observer inserts the price and countdown twice.
My observer looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/r3fZkzwX) and here is my [phtml file](http://pastebin.com/ajhyhtik).
RWD theme has this div for price info:

```
<div class="price-info">
    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?><br>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?><br>
    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?><br>
</div>
```

If I remove the last line with TierPrice, my observer does not duplicate my price, but if I don't then the price is duplicated.
Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 1):

Your observer is currently setup to be called every time a Block is inserted into a page. (This is a bit inefficient as it will be called *hundreds* of times per page load, but we'll ignore that for now)

On line 11 of your observer you are filtering all the blocks by its type: `if ($_type == 'catalog/product_price')` 
This if condition will return true for both the blocks which are included in the calls `getPriceHtml($_product);` and `getTierPriceHtml();` as they are of the same type.

What you need to do is set your Observer to type `singleton` in your XML declaration.
    Company_Module_Model_Observer
    insertBlock
    singleton

This would ensure that on the second call at `getTierPriceHtml`, a second Observer is not created. Now all that is left to do is just put a flag into your `insertBlock` method to ensure that it doesn't insert your countdown template multiple times.